# Google Contact API version 3 [Prefix and Suffix]

Tags: google-contacts-api

I'm currently having trouble with setting the PREFIX and SUFFIX on Google Contacts. I'm using .NET and BATCH contacts from local DB and merging them Google contacts.

Code:

```
c.Name.GivenName = a.Firstname;
c.Name.FamilyName = a.Surname;
c.Name.NamePrefix = a.Prefix;
c.Name.NameSuffix = a.Suffix;

c.BatchData = new GDataBatchEntryData();
c.BatchData.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
c.BatchData.Type = ec != null ? GDataBatchOperationType.update : GDataBatchOperationType.insert;
cf.Entries.Add(c.AtomEntry);

var result = cservice.Batch(cf, new Uri(String.Format("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{0}/full/batch", username)));
```

In debugger i can see the AtomEntry has the correct attributes, but when the batch is executed and BatchResult returns OK (200), then my contacts still don't have the Suffix or Prefix.

So am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation in contacts?

best regards 
Thomas

Comment: I don't see any error with your [code](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/schema/contact_atom.rnc). Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/duYYamq-bkE), be noted that the Prefix is treated as a different field than the First Name, which is when you sort them by first name, it doesn't take into consideration the contents in the prefix field. You could also reread this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) and check if you miss something with your configuration and integration.

Comment: It might be worth to mention that this is Google For Education. I'm not sure if this changes something regarding the contacts.

The contact is created but everything is cleansed and nothing is saved besides the contact. I can see that the Name is taken from the Directory. This is very confusing.